# Ubuntu secure ftp-server that supports per-user download quota setting

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp

Which FTP server will meet the following criteria:

- can run on Ubuntu linux
- secure
- supports a per-user download quota (I would like to limit a user to 1GB download traffic per month)

Thank you

Comment: Asking for the "best" anything is very subjective, and can have no real answer and so your question is likely to get closed. You would be better to rephrase your question to ask something along the lines of "Which FTP server will meet the following criteria I have:...."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few weeks ago I installed and configured ProFTPd http://www.proftpd.org/ and I have to say I like it, I have to admit that I am not using qouta function, but I know that ProFTPd has this function and is not so hard to set it up.
I am also using with ProFTPd web based administration tool ProFTPd administrator http://batland.de/subdomains/codes/index.php/p/proftpdadmin/ (you can change quota for users right there through web interface, of course you have to first configured it).